# pyspark taking too long to start session even though findspark has found it

Tags: pyspark

So the problem I have been encountering is that while I have installed pyspark in windows 10 beforehand and the actual method worked in my previous laptop. This laptop has windows 11 and I have reciprocated the actual steps like previously by installing anaconda and then installing pyspark in a seperate environment. I have made a seperate kernel for the pyspark. But still I am not able to create a session and it stands idle for long without creating the spark session. Serious help needed.

I tried uninstalling and installing again.
I tried installing in the base env of the anaconda.
I tried searching for solutions but didn't find any.
Tried another methods of installation but still same results.